# Does Tony Stark urinate or poop in the Iron Man suit?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe

During the missions, whatever movie you prefer, Tony Stark spend more than 5 hours per mission (given the time passed and the sequence of the movies) in the suit. I was wondering if he has physiologic needs (such as poop or pee) and having the armor, what could he do?

Comment: "Urinate": sophisticated, adult, medical term for liquid elimination. "Poop": Four-year-old's term for solid elimination. I would expect either "Urinate or defecate" or "Pee or poop" but the mixture amuses me (+1 anyway).

Comment: Recommend your changes @ToddWilcox

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, he can. Specifically, he can urinate.

In the second part of Iron Man (2010), Tony is celebrating his birthday with almost 90% of paladium in his body and decided to celebrate like the last party of his life and put his suit for the party. When he's making a speech in front of his guests, he says that many people ask often how to go to the bathroom with the armor and make a joke.

[image: Screenshot of the movie.]
Suddendly, Pepper ask Tony to end the party, Tony try to kiss her and she said:

> You just pee in your suit!

Tony replied Pepper:

> I know but it has (the suit) a filter system. You could drink that water (ex-urine).

Comment: This answer feels incomplete given that we often see him going in or out of his suit but never naked or with what can see as filtering clothes.

Comment: Clearly he's wearing underwear with suitable (all puns intended) attachments

Comment: @olivier that's an intentionally ignored plot hole for the sake of a joke.

Comment: Next question: how could Pepper tell he just pee in the suit? ;)